# slide in/out a div in an angular component when clicking a button

Tags: angular, animation, kendo-ui

I have an angular component in which I have many buttons, when clicking each button takes me to another div of the same component, I am to have an animation of slide in when the new div appears from right to left and the main div from its position to left and then disappear, the reverse goes when I press the back button of the new div to go back to the main div

Note that I am using in my component the kendo library but I did not find a controller that does this animation like the drawer controller does for example

I have tried angular animation and transition but it is not the way that I want it.